Voltage Controlled High Current Source Mosfet selection
I am working on adjustable VCCS targeting 2 to 3A to my 0.5 ohm load.
According to my schematic:

I am controlling the current size through my load (H1, 0.5 ohm) by using DAC function of my MCU. However, although I tried many different NMOSFET, they were out of control due to high heat dissipation issues (Mosfet is burnt or work abnormally).
In my previous question, people recommended me to use heatsink, however, it is not possible due to the limitation in my PCB size and area. Therefore, I would like to change MOSFET to higher Pds NMOSFET like BSC009NE2LS5IATMA1
Previously, my MOSFET was barely matched with 2A condition. But, this MOSFET is with sufficient margin.
Here, Ids VS Vds graph of BSC009NE2LS5IATMA1:
BSC009NE2LS5IATMA1 Datasheet (PDF)
https://www.mouser.hk/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_BSC009NE2LS5I_DataSheet_v02_01_EN-3360566.pdf

would it be fine? Would I encounter the same problem?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Here is the power dissipation spec from the datasheet you linked to:

Notice that the allowed power dissipation is 74 W only if the case is held at 25 C. In other words, this spec applies when an ideal or perfect heat sink is used.
If the heat sink plus package gives an overall thermal resistance from device to ambient of 50 K/W, the allowed thermal dissipation is only 2.5 W. This would be a pretty minimal hat sink.
In the thermal characteristics section they tell you \$6\,{\rm cm}^2\$ of copper area gives \$\Theta_{ja}\$ of 50 K/W. Connecting the drain pad to a large copper region (on an outer layer and preferably with no solder mask and with airflow across it) is the usual way of heat-sinking these kinds of SMT parts.

You can interpolate between those two values to get the allowed dissipation with other heat sinks. The main point is that using no heat sink at all won't reach your goal of dissipating 10 - 15 W.

Here, Ids VS Vds graph of BSC009NE2LS5IATMA1:

The notation at the bottom of the chart that says \$T_c = 25^\circ {\rm C}\$ means this chart only applies when a perfect (0 K/W) heatsink is used to maintain the case temperature equal to 25 C.
TL;DR
No, the part you selected is not able to dissipate 12.5 W without a heatsink.
